# input file with built-in webserser

Tags: php, webserver

Is input file works with the php5.4 built-in webserver ?

When I post a file **$_FILES** array is empty on my local test machine.

This is my form:

```
<form name="publicite" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="dynamique">Fichier Dynamique</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input id="dynamique" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="img">Fichier Image</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input id="img" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
        <button class="btn" type="button">Annuler</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On server side, I just do that:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

And it return:

```
array (size=0)
```

empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a name to the input:

```
<input id="img" type="file" name="file1" />
```

Then **$_FILES** should contain the data from your input with the specified name.

Comment: Hey here its 11:46 am :D no problem :D

Answer (score 2):

You should give a name from the all the fields to access it.

```
<input id="dynamique" type="file" name="dynamique" />
<input id="img" type="file" name="img"/>
```